# thread c# and open a connection to database

Tags: c#, connection, task

I'm trying to figure out best practices on my database connection. 
I have a background (c#).NET application that serves as a report printer. 
My application connect to the first database every 30s and update the second one.

If values changed I generate a report.

I can't use the SqlTableDependency cause I'm not the owner of the first database.
Currently I use tasks :

```
var global_task = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (true) 
        {
            CreatTask();                
            await Task.Delay(30000);
        }
    });    

CreatTask() 
{            
    var   first = Task.Run(() => GetDataDB());                
}    

private void GetDataDB()
{
    Get changed Data;
    Save in the second data base;
    PrintData(changeddata);
}


private void PrintData(changeddata)
{
    PrintReport()

}
```

Is that the best solution?
What are the advantages / disadvantages of keeping one open connection for the application vs 
opening a new connection for every interaction?
What are some common design patterns for this?

Comment: Why not just keep a connection open to both databases and just run queries as and when you need? Also check `connection pooling` (e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx)